# Mostrar checkbox con "checked" al editar un registro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario de registro con varios checkbox en la vista la tengo configurada de esta forma:

`{!!Form::checkbox('admin','1',false,['id'=>'admin', 'class'=>'uk-checkbox'])!!}`

Administrador

Este se guarda en la base de datos sin problema en la migración de laravel lo tengo configurado de esta forma:

```
$table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
```

El usuario que genera el registro tiene la opción de editarlo pero cuando lo intenta hacer los checkboxs no aparecen seleccionados, como hacer para que al momento de consultar dicho registro los checkbox que selecciono al registrarse aparezcan seleccionados al momento de editarlo.

Answer (score 0):

El tercer parámetro es el que hace que el checkbox quede seleccionado o no. Para que quede seleccionado : `TRUE`; para que no quede seleccionado: `FALSE` o `NULL`.

En el código que pones quedaría así:

```
{!!Form::checkbox('admin','1',true,['id'=>'admin', 'class'=>'uk-checkbox'])!!}
```